# Is it possible to use a mocked object as an input for another method up for mocking?

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I created a previous Test method with setup for two mocked objects on a single Data Access and it worked fine. Did another one with same scenario but this turned out fail.

Here's the test method:

```
[Test]
public void UpdateUserPassword_WhenInputsAreCorrect_ReturnsQuerySuccessMessage()
    {
        UpdatePasswordModel input = new UpdatePasswordModel()
        {
            UserName = "john.doe",
            NewPassword = "password1", //password1
            PreviousPassword = "password" //password
        };

        Mock<IUserDataAccess> user = new Mock<IUserDataAccess>();
        Mock<IDailyTimeInDataAccess> timeIn = new Mock<IDailyTimeInDataAccess>();
        Mock<IDailyTimeOutDataAccess> timeOut = new Mock<IDailyTimeOutDataAccess>();

        user.Setup(x => x.UpdatePassword(10000, input.NewPassword)).Returns("User record updated.");
        user.Setup(x => x.GetUser(input.UserName)).Returns(new User()
        {
            UserKey = 10000,
            UserName = "john.doe",
            UserPassword = "LTg9BIob8urwz643K5+pBA=="
        });

        ILoginBusinessRules app = new LoginBusinessRules(user.Object, timeIn.Object, timeOut.Object);

        var output = app.UpdateUserPassword(input);

        Assert.AreEqual("User record updated.", output);
    }
```

Here's the business rule:

```
public string UpdateUserPassword(UpdatePasswordModel model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            return "No data to process.";
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName))
        {
            return "Username is empty.";
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.NewPassword))
        {
            return "New Password is empty.";
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PreviousPassword))
        {
            return "Previous Password is empty.";
        }

        var user = _userDataAccess.GetUser(model.UserName);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return "User not found.";
        }

        if (user.UserPassword != EncryptPassword(model.PreviousPassword))
        {
            return "Previous password does not match.";
        }
        else
        {
            user.UserPassword = EncryptPassword(model.NewPassword);
            user.UpdateDttm = DateTime.Now;
            user.UpdateUserId = model.UserName;

            var result = _userDataAccess.UpdatePassword(user.UserKey, user.UserPassword);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

The test returned a failure. Further debugging told me that this line here is returning null:

```
var result = _userDataAccess.UpdatePassword(user.UserKey, user.UserPassword);
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Setup` uses `input.NewPassword` which from the test is

```
UpdatePasswordModel input = new UpdatePasswordModel() {
    //...
    NewPassword = "password1",
    //...
};

//...

user.Setup(x => x.UpdatePassword(10000, input.NewPassword)).Returns("User record updated.");

//...
```

but in the method under test the method is called with another value

```
//...

user.UserPassword = EncryptPassword(model.NewPassword);

//...

var result = _userDataAccess.UpdatePassword(user.UserKey, user.UserPassword);
```

which wont match what was expected in the setup.

When a mocked member is not invoked with what was expected it will return the default of the return type, which in this case would be *null*

You would need to either make sure that the correct value is used in the setup expectation

For example

```
user
    .Setup(x => x.UpdatePassword(10000, EncryptPassword(input.NewPassword)))
    .Returns("User record updated.");
```

or loosen the expectation of the setup using an argument matcher like `It.IsAny<T>()`

```
   user
    .Setup(x => x.UpdatePassword(10000, It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns("User record updated.");
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the post, yes you can use any object that matches the input type.  Your codes doesn't really know the difference between a "mock" and a "real" object.